# Interrupt a frozen q process via ipc

Tags: kdb

It's possible to interrupt a frozen a q process with ctrl+c :

http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/debugging-kdb#interrupt-q

But is it possible to send SIGINT to process via ipc, so we could interrupt remote q server in ide (or other client) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that exact thing. From https://code.kx.com/q/kb/faq-listbox/ :

```
How to kill long/invalid query on a server?
You can achieve that by sending SIGINT to the server process. In *nix shell, try

$ kill -INT <pid>
```

Worth noting that this only works if the process is in a state to respond to the signal i.e. if it is waiting on swap or is blocked on large numbers of disk reads, it may take a long while to stop itself.

Comment: Thanks, actually what I want to achieve is that :

when we execute some q code in atom/vscode/qstudio (connected to remote q server), sometimes it will freeze the server. We have to go to terminal to press ctrl+c to stop the current query. I would like to stop it directly on vscode via node-q ipc, so that we can directly stop current job remotely on editor.

Comment: You need something on the same server or able to run via ssh etc.  In a previous life I worked with an internal GUI that interfaced with a broker service that would create q processes on your behalf and could then be used to send the SIGINT to cancel queries.  Unless you have something like that it's going to be tricky.